# How can I view the mobile data usage for each application for a given day?

Tags: mobile-data, 9.0-pie, data-monitoring, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I view the mobile data usage for each application for a given day?

[image]

I use Android 9 on Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using a third-party data usage application like [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&hl=en)

With 3G Watchdog you can have finer breakdown of data usage down to individuals application with options to view data usage per period including real time, day, week or month.

[image] [image]